# How to print custom text on the other side of paper html css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

hi im wonder how can i do this ..
let say i have html page like this ..

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>header</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- maybe 10000 reords of files and each -->
        <!-- file have different amount of note chars -->
        @foreach($files as $flie)
            <tr><td>{{$flie['note']}}</td></tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

now there is option in print preview to print on both side
[image]

what i want is how can i add hidden div to be printed on the other side of the paper always
and nothing printing on the other side except that hidden div and add this property to the dive

```
page-break-after: always
```

how can i check if the page is full in print and show the div with property `page-break-after: always`

Comment: can you wright the code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you were pretty close,
if we add  **page-break-after: always**; and **page-break-before: always;** with visibility set only for print, it should do the trick.
I have pasted the sample html below,

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    
    @media print {
        .pagebreak {
            clear: both;
            page-break-after: always;
            page-break-before: always;
    
            visibility: visible !important;
        }
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td>header</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cell 5</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cell 6</td></tr>
           
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
    <div style="visibility: hidden; " class="pagebreak">
    Test
    </div>
    <script>
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay i did this https://ibb.co/1MB2M7f and this is the result https://ibb.co/8P5S88s and the pagebreak only showing in the last page like this https://ibb.co/ccxJVqb how can i make the pagebreak print between printed pages

Comment: Oh, I understood you have a non breaking table, so basically you want a page with div content in between table page breaks...
I will try to update it.